# Hibernate: store embedded map of primitves

Tags: java, hibernate

How to store following the entity using Hibernate?

```
@Entity
class A {
  private Map<String, String> b;

  // getters and setters omitted
}
```

Comment: `@ElementCollection`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393780/5449250)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing a Map<String,String> using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393649/storing-a-mapstring-string-using-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [@ElementCollection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues)

Example usage:

```
@Entity
public class User {

   public String getLastname() { ...}

   @ElementCollection
   @CollectionTable(name="Nicknames", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
   @Column(name="nickname")
   public Set<String> getNicknames() { ... } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Save**

Here an example:

```
A variable = new A();
variable.b(your_variable);
```

Then

```
session.save(varible);
```

can be used.
Or you mean to store in a database by the storage? 
Then will be so:

```
  SessionFactory factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();   
  Session session=factory.openSession();  
  Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();   
  A e1=new A();  
  e1.setb(your_variable);  
  session.persist(e1);
  t.commit();
  session.close();
```

**Mention**: your naming is quite bad. You should put something else!

Also, with the @ElementCollection annotation you can use java.util.Map collections. In the declaration of your class (in your case, A).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should use @ElementCollection and @CollectionTable from JPA: [How to annotate Map<Entity,INTEGER> with JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267131/how-to-annotate-mapentity-integer-with-jpa/33269388)